# How to get notify if transaction got failed, dropped, or successes

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapps, evm, ropsten

I am new in dapps world and I want to deduct balance/points when a user buys an item currently I am unable to update balance because sometimes transaction got failed, dropped, or successes after 30 seconds to 2 minutes time, so how to subscribe or listen to transaction event than I can perform some action.

```
redeemPoints(from, to, price, (err, res) => {
    if(!err){
      console.log(res) //old value of balance 
    }
})
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I wanna deduct point when user buy some product, and I even don't know  the transaction is success, fail, or drop transaction taking 1 - 10 minutes time

Comment: @UmairAhmed do you mean that you change the state of another database according to the result of the transaction on the blockchain ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use events in the solidity smart contract. In simple terms, the purpose of an Event is to provide JavaScript callbacks in a user interface, which allows you to execute code based on whether or not the event was successful or if it errored.

Comment: I need to fire an event from ABI and listen on client right ?

Comment: Yes, you need to trigger an event in the smart contract and watch it in a front end.